# Fill new column conditionally if previous column contained specific word

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I would like to fill a new column conditionally using mutate. A new variable should correspond to a value if it was presented in the reference column or not if yes then define a new variable name based on this condition.

My dataframe:
[Player stat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyOqp.png)

```
short_name, overall, positions, value_eur
1   L. Messi    94  RW  95500000
2   Cristiano Ronaldo   93  ST  58500000
3   Neymar Jr   92  LW  105500000
4   J. Oblak    91  GK  77500000
5   E. Hazard   91  LW  90000000
6   K. De Bruyne    91  CAM 90000000
7   M. ter Stegen   90  GK  67500000
8   V. van Dijk 90  CB  78000000
9   L. Modric   90  CM  45000000
10  M. Salah    90  RW  80500000
11  K. Mbappé   89  ST  93500000
12  K. Koulibaly    89  CB  67500000
```

I want to create new column call my_pos and define by column "positions" where if GK appear data should be "GK", if 'CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB' data should be "DEF" and so on like code below.

**Attempt to define new column with below condition**

```
    d %>% mutate(my_pos = case_when(positions == 'GK' ~ "GK",
                            positions =='CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB' ~ "DEF", 
                            positions =='CDM','CM','CAM','LM','RM' ~ "MID",
                            positions =='CF','ST','LW','RW' ~ "FWD"))
```

**Error**

```
'> d %>%
+   mutate(my_pos = case_when(positions == 'GK' ~ "GK",
+                             positions =='CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB' ~ "DEF", 
+                             positions =='CDM','CM','CAM','LM','RM' ~ "MID",
+                             positions =='CF','ST','LW','RW' ~ "FWD"))
Error: Case 2 (`positions == "GK" ~ "GK"`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace'
```

Please guide me on how to fix this.

Comment: I think you just want it to say `positions %in% c('CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB') ~ "DEF"`

Comment: Oh thank @svenhalvorson, I able to fix it with the code you guided !! <br>
<code>data %>% mutate(my_pos = case_when(positions %in% c('GK') ~ "GK",
                                positions %in% c('CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB') ~ "DEF", 
                                positions %in% c('CDM','CM','CAM','LM','RM') ~ "MID",
                                positions %in% c('CF','ST','LW','RW') ~ "FWD"))

Comment: You need to declare a vector, not just give a bunch of strings, such as `c('CB','LB','LWB','RB','RWB')`